# Read file owned by a group I belong to in Docker rootless

Tags: docker, permissions, file-permissions

On my host I have a file `/path/to_file/my_file` in rwxrwx--- mode. This file belongs to a group "A" which my user is part of, but is owned by another user. I can read this file without problem as I'm in group A.

I start a rootless docker container with:

```
docker run -it --user $(id -u):$(id -g A) -v /path/to_file/my_file:/data --rm my-image:latest
```

And inside the container I run:

```
cat /data/my_file
```

Which gives this error:

> cat: my_file: Permission denied

Command `ls -l` gives:

> -rwxrwx--- 1 nobody nogroup        188 Aug 10 08:30 my_file

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the uid/gid of your user, the uid/gid of the file you are trying to share, and what are the contents of `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` on the host?

Comment: My user has uid 11424, gid 100, the file has uid 966, gid 966. The files in /etc are identical, the user who owns the file has entry 63307776:65536 and I have 748683264:65536

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rootless is implemented on top of user namespaces. And user namespaces are implemented by looking up your user in `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` to create a range of UIDs and GIDs. If each of the files were to say `yourname:100000:65536`, then uid 0 in the namespace would map to 100000 on the host, and uid 1234 in the namespace would map to 101234 on the host.

Volume mounts currently do not map uid/gid's between the host and the container, the numeric values are identical in both. It's one of the big reasons I suspect Docker does not enable user namespaces by default.

Any uid or gid outside of the subuid/subgid range won't have any access to users in the namespace. The user namespace doesn't have the concept of what your user has access to on the host, so your group access on the host is not taken into consideration.

To give access to the container, you'll want to change the file uid/gid on the host to a value in the range that the container user would have read/write access. Other options include copying the file into the container, e.g.

```bash
cat /path/to_file/my_file \
  | docker run -i --rm -v appdata:/data busybox /bin/sh -c "cat >/data/my_file"

docker run -it -v appdata:/data --rm my-image:latest
```